# Error Bex while running my qt application

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I am writing an application to convert markdown to html. And built a dll based on "cpp-markdown" for this purpose, named markdown2html.dll. The dll runs well in my test program, but failed in my qt application. Here's the code:

```
QString tNotesTextEditor::markdown2html(QString articleContents){

QLibrary convertLib(tr("markdown2html.dll"));
std::string result;
if(convertLib.load()){
    QMessageBox::information(NULL, "OK", "DLL load is OK!");
    typedef std::string (*Fun)(std::string);
    Fun convertFunc = (Fun)convertLib.resolve("markdown2HTML");
    if(convertFunc){
        QMessageBox::information(NULL, "OK", "Function is found");
        std::string locale_text = articleContents.toLocal8Bit().constData();
        QMessageBox::information(NULL, "OK", "to stdstring is well");
        result = convertFunc("helloworld");
        QMessageBox::information(NULL, "OK", "Function works well");
        //QMessageBox::information(NULL, "OK", QString::fromLocal8Bit(result.c_str()));
        return QString::fromStdString(result.c_str());
    } else {
        QMessageBox::information(NULL, "OK", "Function not found");
        return NULL;
    }
} else {
    QMessageBox::information(NULL, "OK", "Lib not found");
    return NULL;
}

}
```

The "works well" message has never shown, and I get the error message:

```
问题事件名称: BEX
应用程序名:  tNotes_client.exe
应用程序版本: 0.0.0.0
应用程序时间戳:    532af665
故障模块名称: StackHash_0a9e
故障模块版本: 0.0.0.0
故障模块时间戳:    00000000
异常偏移:   0028d3c9
异常代码:   c0000005
异常数据:   badc0de1
OS 版本:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
区域设置 ID:    2052
其他信息 1: 0a9e
其他信息 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
其他信息 3: 0a9e
其他信息 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I have closed the DEP to my app as the site says:
[Problem Event Name: BEX, error message](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_programs/problem-event-name-bex-error-message/cf5baf73-0877-4070-abfb-a2c3a17a9e10)

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Chinese error messages are not helpful. Also it could help if you provide the include header of your DLL so people can see the functions signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the point that the default compiler of my Qt creator is mingw, but the dll is compiled with VC. There should be some diference between these two compiler and the std::string (in my case, "helloworld") cannot passed to the function in DLL correctly.

So my solution is compiling all codes with the same compiler.
Thanks!